# EclipseLink MOXy - DynamicType is maxOccurs greater than 1

Tags: eclipselink, moxy

I'm using MOxy to load an XSD at run-time and understand the structure of an XML matching the XSD. To clarify, I don't yet have any XML matching the XSD, I just want to understand the possible structure such an XML might have.

My problem is I can't find a way to check if an element is a list of elements, in other words if this element has a maxOccurs greater than 1.

I get an object of type DynamicType and I don't see any difference between an object matching an xs:element with one occurrence and an object for xs:element with more than one occurrence.

If MOxy can't do this, are there other libraries that can?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better library to explore an XSD - apache XMLSchema.
This library let's me walk the XSD and retrieve among other things the maxOccurs attribute.